# Looking for hints to solve this dynamic programming problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to improve my problem solving skills for programming interviews and am trying to solve [this problem](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_2799_en.html). I have a feeling it can be solved using dynamic programming but the recursive relationship is not obvious to me.

To select the first three choir singers I simply use brute force. Since there are only `20 Choose 3 = 1140` ways to pick them. At first I thought `dp[a][b][c]` could represent the shortest song with three choir singers with remaining breath `a, b, c`. If I could calculate this using `dp[a][b][c] = 1 + dp[a - 1][b - 1][c - 1]`, but what should be done when any of the indices equal `0`, which choir singer should be substituted in. Additionally, we cannot reuse the `dp` array, because say in one instance we start with choir singers with breath `a, b, c` and in the second instance `d, e, f`. Once the first instance has been calculated and the `dp` array filled; the second instance may need to use `dp[i][j][k]` computed by the first instance. Since this value depends on the available choir singers in the first instance, and the available singers in both instances are not the same, `dp[i][j][k]` may not be possible in the second instance. This is because the shortest song length `dp[i][j][k]` may use choir singers which in the second instance are already being used.

I am out of ideas to tackle this problem and there is no solution anywhere. Could someone give me some hints to solve it?

#### Problem statement

We have `N` singers, who each have a certain time they can sing for and need 1 second to recover once out of breath. What is the minimum song they can sing, where three singers are singing at all times and where they all three finish singing simultaneously?

Input:

Input
3 < N <= 20
N integers Fi (1 <= Fi <= 10, for all 1 <= i <= N)

Comment: I added Python code to my answer (as well as adding the check to avoid a singer repeating, which I neglected before).

Comment: @TomFinet it looks pretty similar, I'm not sure. Good point about more than one singer being disallowed from repeating - I have to give that more thought, especially since they are allowed to continue if they just swap "places." Could the method for ruling out singers be curtailing some of the states?

Comment: Do you mean the code for generating the initial states is curtailing some states? @גלעדברקן

Comment: @bingbong I meant countV but maybe that one too, I don't know.

Comment: Well, to check if a singer is available, I count the number of occurrences of that singer in the used singers vector (what countV is doing) and if it is larger or equal to the number of singers of that breath length, that singer must be used. Do you think I am counting wrong in countV? @גלעדברקן

Comment: Do you have an example of failing input and its expected output? Also, if you have an example where you think my code sees more states, check if the first states that initialise the queue are the same as with yours. If they are, perhaps we could rule out the problem being there. There is only one other place that I can think of where states would seem to get limited, which is countV.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the idea.

At each point in the singing, the current state can be represented by who the singers are, how long they have been singing, and which ones are currently out of breath.  And from each state we need to transition to a new state, which is every singer out of breath is ready to sing again, every singer singing is good for one less turn, and new singers might be chosen.

Done naively, there are up to 20 choose 3 singers, each of which can be in 10 current states, plus up to 2 more who are out of breath.  This is 175560000 combined states you can be in.  That's too many, we need to be more clever to make this work.

Being more clever, we do **not** have 20 differentiable singers.  We have 10 buckets of singers based on how long they can sing for.  If a singer can sing for 7 turns, they **can't** be in 10 states if currently singing, but only 7.  We do **not** care whether the two can sing for 7 turns are at 4 and 3 turns left or 3 and 4, they are the same.  This introduces a lot of symmetries.  Once we take care of all of the symmetries, that reduces the number of possible states that we might be in from hundreds of millions to (usually) tens of thousands.

And now we have a state transition for our DP which is `dp[state1]` to `dp[state2]`.  The challenge being to produce a state representation that takes advantage of these symmetries that you can use as keys to your data structure.

UPDATE:

The main loop of the code would look like this Python:

```
while not finished:
    song_length += 1
    next_states = set()
    for state in current_states:
        for next_state in transitions(state):
            if is_finished(next_state):
                finished = True # Could break out of loops here
            else:
                next_states.add(next_state)
    current_states = next_states
```

Most of the challenge is a good representation of a state, and your `transitions` function.

Comment: So for `N` singers, instead of looking at `N Choose 3` starting singers, if there are two singers with the same breath, I just look at one of them in combination with two other distinct singers to make all triples of singers that have distinct breaths. I then look at all triples with two singers with the same breath and then all triples where all singers have the same breath. This avoids doing the same computation redundantly. I'm not sure if this is what you mean't by: "We do not care whether the two can sing for 7 turns are at 4 and 3 turns left or 3 and 4, they are the same"?

Comment: But maybe you mean't: if we start with singers `7 5 3` and after 3 seconds we replace the 3 with a 7, then the new combination is `4 2 7`, but the singers being used with full breath are `7 5 7`, so it doesn't matter if we do the same thing but with the other 7 singer being used first, as the two 7 singers are indistinguishable. Is this what you mean't @btilly?

Comment: That is indeed what I meant.  So your representation might look in JSON like `{7: [4, 3], 6: [6], "out": [2]}` meaning that 2 singers who can last 7 seconds are singing, they have 4 and 3 left, 1 singer who can last 6 seconds is singing, and has 6 turns left and a singer who can last 2 is out of breath.  This state would have to transition to `{7: [3, 2], 6: [5], "out": []}`.  Worrying about taking advantage of all available symmetries is more important than the efficiency of working with the representation.  Eventually you would like both.

Comment: so using the symmetry I can reduce the computations needed by ignoring the redundant states. But I don't see how that could help with finding a relation between two states.

Comment: @bingbong At a given moment you have a set of possible states that you can be in.  From each state we can calculate the set of possible states that you can next be in.  (Anyone out of breath recovers, anyone singing reduces how long for by 1.  If someone ends singing, they are out of breath and someone else starts singing.) Those state transitions should be most of your logic.  When we first find a point of time where the next state has 3 singers catching their breath, the song ends.  I will add pseudocode.

Comment: ok seems more like a clever brute force problem to me then. It doesn't feel like dynamic programming if I'm generating all possible next states and going through all of them.

Comment: I suppose, if from starting singers `A B C` we can get to state `X Y Z` with `T` time elapsed and `O1 O2` taking breaths, which we have already found the minimum song for, then dp can be used. Is this correct?

Comment: @TomFinet You can efficiently represent it with 8 numbers.  For singers 1-3, max breath followed by current left.  Followed by max breath of out of breath singers (0 meaning not out of breath).  With singers always ordered by max breath then current breath.  My first breath example would then be, `[7,4,7,3,6,6,2,0]`.  It then transitions to `[7,3,7,2,6,5,0,0]`.  And each number has a maximum value < 255 so you can use 1 byte each.  That said, the win from a set of text JSON values to a packed array is much smaller than the win of any representation that uses all symmetries.

Comment: @TomFinet The number of combinations that can actually occur are far, far less than your naive 10^8.  And no, we don't need an 8-dimensional array.  Just a set of such represented with either a hash or binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

The state in terms of memoisation seems unrelated to the time elapsed since the start. Take any starting position,

```
a, b, c
```

where `a, b, c` are chosen magnitudes (how long each singer can hold their breath), and `a` is the smallest magnitude. We have

```
a, b, c
t = 0
```

and it's the same as:

```
0, b - a, c - a
t = a
```

So let's define the initial state with smallest magnitude `a` as:

```
b, c, ba, ca
  where ba = b - a
        ca = c - a
t = a
```

From here, every transition of the state is similar:

```
new_a <- x
  where x is a magnitude in
  the list that can be available
  together with b and c. (We only
  need to try each such unique
  magnitude once during this
  iteration. We must also prevent
  a singer from repeating.)

  let m = min(new_a, ba, ca)

  then the new state is:
    u, v, um, vm
    t = t + m
      where u and v are from the
      elements of [new_a, b, c] that
      aren't associated with m, and um
      and vm are their pairs from
      [new_a, ba, ca] that aren't m,
      subtracted by m.
```

The state for memoisation of visited combinations can be only:

```
[(b, ba), (c, ca)] sorted by
the tuples' first element
```

with which we can prune a branch in the search if the associated `t` that is reached is equal or higher to the minimal one seen for that state.

Example:

```
2 4 7 6 5
```

Solution (read top-down):

```
4 5 6
7 4 5
  2
```

States:

```
u v um vm
5 6 1 2
t = 4

new_a = 7
m = min(7, 1, 2) = 1 (associated with 5)
7 6 6 1
t = 5

new_a = 4
m = min(4, 6, 1) = 1 (associated with 6)
4 7 3 5
t = 6

new_a = 5
m = min(5, 3, 5) = 3 (associated with 4)
5 7 2 2
t = 9

new_a = 2
m = min(2, 2, 2) = 2 (associated with 2)
5 7 0 0
t = 11
```

Python code:

```
import heapq
from itertools import combinations

def f(A):
  mag_counts = {}

  for x in A:
    if x in mag_counts:
      mag_counts[x] = mag_counts[x] + 1
    else:
      mag_counts[x] = 1

  q = []

  seen = set()

  # Initialise the queue with unique starting combinations
  for comb in combinations(A, 3):
    sorted_comb = tuple(sorted(comb))
    if not sorted_comb in seen:
      (a, b, c) = sorted_comb
      heapq.heappush(q, (a, (b-a, b), (c-a, c), a))
    seen.add(sorted_comb)

  while q:
    (t, (ba, b), (ca, c), prev) = heapq.heappop(q)

    if ba == 0 and ca == 0:
      return t

    for mag in mag_counts.keys():
      # Check that the magnitude is available
      # and the same singer is not repeating.
      [three, two] = [3, 2] if mag != prev else [4, 3]
      if mag == b == c and mag_counts[mag] < three:
        continue
      elif mag == b and mag_counts[mag] < two:
        continue
      elif mag == c and mag_counts[mag] < two:
        continue
      elif mag == prev and mag_counts[mag] < 2:
        continue

      m = min(mag, ba, ca)

      if m == mag:
        heapq.heappush(q, (t + m, (ba-m, b), (ca-m, c), m))
      elif m == ba:
        heapq.heappush(q, (t + m, (mag-m, mag), (ca-m, c), b))
      else:
        heapq.heappush(q, (t + m, (mag-m, mag), (ba-m, b), c))

  return float('inf')

As = [
  [3, 2, 3, 3], # 3
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 4], # 3
  [2, 4, 7, 6, 5] # 11
]

for A in As:
  print A, f(A)
```

Comment: @TomFinet btilly might have a point by having states update as we steadily increment the song-length. That restricts endless search branches, and guarantees the first termination is optimal.

Comment: Why does it restrict endless search if we go 1 second instead of what you suggest? @גלעדברקן

Comment: @bingbong depth-first could be pursuing branches that continually maintain some difference between the singers, therefore never terminating. If the problem is guaranteed to have a (reasonable) solution, breadth-first  should find it and can stop the search.

Comment: So we need a breadth first search. And the first instance where a song ends is the answer? Does this mean we do not need memoization?

Comment: @bingbong can you please provide the input that causes segmentation fault?

Comment: The test case for 5 singers is
1 2 3 2 4

Comment: @bingbong if we are increasing the time by 1 each time, the first termination is clearly the shortest song. I'm not completely certain but it seems to me we may want a "visited" set that would prevent us from regenerating states.

Comment: @bingbong it seems to me that running my idea with a priority queue on `t` for the choice of next state, should also terminate, guaranteeing optimality.

Comment: Could you try to code it up and update your answer for me to understand?

Comment: Makes sense, if we prioritize states with singers with less breath it would examine them in the correct order

Comment: @bingbong prioritise the selection of the next state to work with (to generate new states) based on time-elapsed. Prioritising singers with less breath wouldn't necessarily guarantee either optimality or ending the search. From each state, generate all possible (unique) next states.

Comment: @TomFinet yes, that's how I understand it as well. The code doesn't include a "visited" state cache. It could possibly be helpful for some input, although I'm not certain.